# How to Test All Iterative Conditions Are True (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

Let's say I have one array with subarrays and another array like this:

```
var arr1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
var arr2 = [3,4];
```

I want to print all of the subarrays from `arr1` that contain every element of `arr2`. But since this is just one example of what I want, I also want to be able to apply this to any set of arrays that sort of look like this.

**How would I create a for-loop that can test if each `arr1[i]` contains all elements of `arr2`?** So far I have this code, but it only checks if a single element matches an element in each subarray. I've been trying to look up ways to change this to make the function I need, but I'm drawing a blank on solutions.

```
var newArr = [];

for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    if (arr1[i].hasOwnProperty(arr2[j])) {
       newArr.splice(-1, 0, arr1[i]);
    }
}

return newArr;
```

Comment: `hasOwnproperty` does not do what you think it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to iterate the `arr1`, and remove sub arrays if they don't pass the [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) test - check that every item in `arr2` is in the sub array using [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (or [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) if supported).

```js
var arr1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [1, 3, 6, 4]];
var arr2 = [3,4];

var result = arr1.filter(function(sub) {
  return arr2.every(function(n) {
    return sub.indexOf(n) !== -1; // or sub.includes(n)
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as follows;

```js
var arr1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]],
    arr2 = [3,4];
    res = arr1.filter(sa => sa.every(n => arr2.includes(n)));
console.log(res);
```

Wow there is a very similar answer.. Then lets do it with a `.reduce()`

```js
var arr1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]],
    arr2 = [3,4,5,6];
    res = arr1.reduce((r,s) => s.every(n => arr2.includes(n)) ? r.concat(s):r,[]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I think you need to swap `arr2` with `sa` to match the description "*the subarrays that contain every element of `arr2`*".

Comment: @Bergi :) Sorry for being non conventional... It's my 5th beer as of now that i am sipping. May be that's why I can not tell the difference. Don't get me wrong i like you correcting me. Could you please tell, what's the difference..?

Comment: With `a = [1,2]` an `b = [1]`, all elements of `b` are contained in `a` but `b` does not contain all elements of `a`.

Comment: @Bergi Fair enough.. :)